# Best CMS for internet and intranet site

Tags: cms, internet, intranet

My client asked me to code site for intranet (employees) and internet (customers). I have many skills with Wordpress. Is (and how can be it done) wordrpess enough for intranet and internet?

What do you recommend?

Intranet site should:

- have system for internal employees communication
- to do list
- possibility to upload media (and organize them)
- timetable management system (diary, calendar, events and so on)

Internet: my client is tourist board agency for main city

- publish articles
- divide site to separate parts (travelling, restaurants, public transport, events ... and so on)

My question is, do you have any skills with something like this?
What CMS is the best for this?
Is there any way to coordinate internet and intranet site somehow?

[image: how it should works]

Comment: Have you tried looking at **Joomla** or **Drupal**?

Comment: Can you specify the environment in which the cms will be or can be? For example `Liferay`(is already an answer) can definitely do the job but it also needs an application-server and some basic knowledge of java and you already mentioned `Wordpress` as your main skill which is in Php.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I thing Liferay is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These requirements match [Liferay](http://liferay.com/) perfectly.

Each site shows differently depending whether the user is:

- not logged in
- logged in visitor
- logged in employee
- and any group structure you want

You can define sites, sections, pages, etc.

There are social features like wiki, [chat](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15392476),

[That extension](https://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/28090247) can be used as a basic todo list, and on the other end of the spectrum you can use [Activiti workflows](http://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/28884606) for great inter-employee task management.

The [document library](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Document+Library+Portlet) allows you to upload documents, via the web or even via WebDAV (that you can mount in Windows Explorer/Finder/Nautilus).

[Calendars](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/administration/-/ai/calend-3) are a strong feature of Liferay, with good integration with other features.

Of course you can publish articles and separate them in different pages/tabs/sections/sites.

Liferay is free, and open source.

Comment: I looked it and I think this is what I was looking for and maybe this CMS is my next favourite. I will try it on my second web server.
@NicolasRaoul are you one of developers team for this CMS?

Comment: @PodujatieEu: No but my company is a Liferay platinum partner: http://aegif.jp/oc/product/liferay.html

Comment: It is in japanese and I do not understand, but I believe you :D 
Thank you for your tip, it is very useful CMS. I will try it and see what it can and cannot do it. Can I contact you if I will have some problem with it? (with coding and customizations)

Comment: @PodujatieEu: There’s a [liferay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/liferay) tag on [so] ;-)